# Limit with fractional part $\lim \limits_{n\to \infty}\{(2+\sqrt{3})^n\}$

Tags: real-analysis, number-theory

Evaluate $\lim \limits_{n\to \infty}\{(2+\sqrt{3})^n\}$, where $\{\cdot\}$ - is fractional part.

Sorry but I have any ideas. I used binomial theorem but no results. By the way I know that $[(2+\sqrt{3})^n]$ is always odd number.

I would be really grateful if anyone shows a proof.

Comment: Fractional part ???

Comment: *Hint.* Can you check that $(2+\sqrt{3})^n + (2-\sqrt{3})^n$ is always an integer?

Comment: @SangchulLee, Yes I know this fact. It's not so difficult.

Comment: Also notice that $0 < (2-\sqrt{3})^n < 1$ and consequently $\{ (2+\sqrt{3})^n \} = 1 - (2-\sqrt{3})^n$.

Comment: @SangchulLee, How you get $\{(2+\sqrt{3})^n\}=1-(2-\sqrt{3})^n$?

Comment: Let me simplify the situation: If $n$ is an integer and $0 < \delta < 1$, then can you check that $\{n-\delta\} = 1-\delta$?

Comment: @SangchulLee, Yes I can.

Comment: Then what bothers you to jump into the conclusion? You can simply take $n$ and $\delta$ as $(2+\sqrt{3})^n + (2-\sqrt{3})^n \in \Bbb{Z}$ and $(2-\sqrt{3})^n \in (0, 1)$.

Comment: @SangchulLee, Thanks a lot! Nice solution! +1

Comment: @SangchulLee..i have  one  doubts  ?  How {$(2 + \sqrt 3)$ } =  $1 - (2 + \sqrt 3)^n $???  as according to ur  formula  {$n - \delta $} = $1- \delta$    . My   confusion  is that   how  {$n - \delta$} ={$(2 + \sqrt 3)^n$ } ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT:** $$(2+\sqrt3)^n+(2-\sqrt3)^n=\lfloor(2+\sqrt3)^n\rfloor+1$$

Arrange and put the limits.

Comment: How you get this identity?

Comment: It can be proven easily once you know that $(2+\sqrt3)^n+(2-\sqrt3)^n$ is an integer. Try it.

Comment: Fix the typos .

Comment: @Aniket, This identity is wrong for $n=2$.

Comment: "Arrange and put the limits": what do you mean ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust Thanks for helping. Typos fixed.

Comment: @YvesDaoust On rearranging the terms from R.H.S. to L.H.S. ,you get the expression in the question. The limit remains to be calculated only then.

Comment: This doesn't tell how the identity was obtained.

Comment: @RFZ Corrected the typos in the expression. Does my identity look clearer now?

Comment: @YvesDaoust It's a hint, not a full-fledged answer.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that $2+\sqrt3$ is a root of $x^2-4x+1=0$, which corresponds to the recurrence equation

$$a_{n+2}=4a_{n+1}-a_n.$$

The general solution is $a_n=a_+(2+\sqrt3)^n+a_-(2-\sqrt3)^n$, and taking $a_+=a_-=1$, we have

$$a_0=2\\a_1=4,\\a_n=(2+\sqrt3)^n+(2-\sqrt3)^n\in\mathbb Z.$$

As $0<2-\sqrt3<1$, the second term goes to zero by positive values, and the requested limits is $$1.$$