# Fractional part of $(3+\sqrt{2})^n$

Tags: limits, number-theory, fractional-part

For $r\in\mathbb{R}$, define $\Vert{r}\Vert:=\inf_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}\vert r-n\vert$.
By [Question 4208947](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4208947/evaluate-lim-n-to-infty-32-sqrt-2n-where-x-is-the-fractional/4208949#4208949) and [Question 1536761](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1536761/limit-with-fractional-part-lim-limits-n-to-infty-2-sqrt3n?rq=1), we know that $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\Vert(3+2\sqrt{2})^n\Vert=0$ and $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\Vert(2+\sqrt{3})^n\Vert=0$. The method is interesting but can only be applied to restricted numbers. I am wondering whether $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\Vert(3+\sqrt{2})^n\Vert$ exists and is there $s\in \mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$ such that $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\Vert(3+\sqrt{2})^n\cdot s\Vert=0$.

Any advice would be helpful. Thanks!

Comment: It is a question in the https://damo.alibaba.com/alibaba-global-mathematics-competition . Please do not post any answer until the contest has finished.

Comment: @Linh do you know alibaba will post official solutions? Haven't been able to find any.

Comment: Unlikely there's an official solution for this. It's likely to be asked on AoPS.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an obligatory graph answer that does not fit in the comments. [Link](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJxVz8FOwzAMBuB7pb7DL3FJRIVaduNV0GBZ6rBIbVJsR8vengSJA77a_2d7pYBgqn0bB7Ri0sIJgZ035oRnyDerebX2o9pxGIcnvCSzzPNs4fN-FCWB3gjy2K95ix5UDyaRmBM0o0_iGhXO-9LMRxfuUW-5aMtFmdCaQrR3xikux5b1gpWCK5tKN7Z8J_4HuLTCuyJtNzFnHgfxTpX4s6fNu6nT709_p1qEzKiICezSF5llwmle7Nn-AGdbUDA=&lang=sage&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==) to Sage for you to test yourself! It plots $y = \{ (3 + \sqrt{2})^n \}$. As expected, it behaves randomly. I wonder if something said about its pseudorandomness i.e. it's distributed evenly across $[0, 1)$, but it seems difficult.

[image]